# Как получить значение запроса, в котором есть пробел

Tags: golang, request

Имею url по типу
../upload?tag=..

Нужно получить значение тега
Что есть сейчас:

```
route.HandleFunc("/upload", Handler.Upload).Methods(http.MethodPost)
```

И далее в функции вытаскиваю тег так:

```
tag := r.URL.Query().Get("tag")
```

Работает только в том случае, если передается тег без пробела.
Как можно решить проблему?

Весь код с ошибкой:
main:

```
func NewServer(settings *config.Settings) *Server {
    return &Server{
        settings: settings,
    }
}

type Server struct {
    server   *http.Server
    settings *config.Settings
}

func (s *Server) StartServer() {
    mux := NewMux()
    route := mux.StartRouter()

    s.server = &http.Server{
        Addr:    fmt.Sprintf(":%d", s.settings.Port),
        Handler: route,
    }

    go s.server.ListenAndServe()
    fmt.Printf("HTTP server started on %d\n", s.settings.Port)
}

func (s *Server) StopServer() {
    s.server.Close()
    fmt.Printf("HTTP server stopped\n")
}
```

mux:

```
func NewMux() *Mux {
    return &Mux{
    }
}

type Mux struct {
}

func (m *Mux) StartRouter() *mux.Router {
    route := mux.NewRouter()
    handler := handlers.NewHandler()
    route.HandleFunc("/upload", handler.Upload).Methods(http.MethodPost)
    return route
}
```

handler:

```
type Handler struct {
}

func NewHandler() *Handler {
    return &Handler{
    }
}

func (h *Handler) Upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tag := r.URL.Query().Get("tag")
    if tag != "" {

    }
}
```

Если тэг без пробела - ок, если с пробелом - 500 
(Например ошибка при такой ссылке: ../upload?tag=f%20f

Comment: Рекомендую посмотреть ещё на прокси.  Например, если перед сервисом стоит криво настроенный _Nginx._

Comment: Какой текст ошибки в случае 500?